# In the context of 1 Corinthians 7:10-15, is a Christian free to remarry if his Christian spouse falls away from God and divorces?

Tags: marriage, divorce

1 Corinthians 7:10-15 does not mention about fallen away or disfellowshiped spouses.

If a baptized believing spouse falls away from God and leaves the church, into which group of people does this new situation moves to: the two believers group or the group of believers married to unbelievers?

What would be the conclusion of this, would the faithfull believer be free to remarry?

Comment: Verse 15 does seem to say that. This might be better asked on [Biblical Hermeneutics.](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @fredsbend [They already asked there](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/18629/2757)

Comment: Does the response vary by denomination? As I read the Catholic Code of Canon Law, for example, the Christian who has not fallen away is **very definitely not** free to remarry.

Comment: On BH to ask this question you would need to change the scope to be more specifically about the text itself and the original context, not it's application to Christians. In this site, you would need to change the scope to ask about a specific theological tradition's views on this matter. "Christianity" is too broad a scope as different groups have different takes on issue like this and we are not here to determine who is right, only document what extant groups beliefs are.